# Watch for data change from a monogdb document. via ReactJS and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

is there an efficient way to watch for data changes for a MongoDB document?

E.g.

```
{
   "liveDiscussionID": "LF0012803891",
   ...,
   "comment": [
     {"userID": "Z0001", "text": "Hey Guys!"},
     ...       
   ]
}
```

I want to listen to changes for this document, when a new comment comes in, the ReactJS view gets updated with the new information.

For now, I am using my ReactJS web app to call a NodeJS route every 15 seconds.

Comment: Any help will be greatly appreciated :) ! Thanks guys

Comment: Maybe this'll help, even though i don't think it's a good idea to put it inside front end code https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/changeStream

I'm thinking of a WebSocket backend that provides this change subscription via an api